# Why is Mac OS X 10.6 using /usr/lib to start Apache when I compiled PHP using /opt/local/lib?

Tags: mac, php, apache-http-server

PHP 5.3.3 compiled on Mac OS X 10.6 - using `/usr/lib` when trying to start Apache... rather than `/opt/local/lib` specified when PHP was configured.

Why is it trying to load from `/usr/lib` when I specified in my configure not to?

> httpd: Syntax error on line 115 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib\n Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so\n Reason: Incompatible library version: libphp5.so requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0

The error message above refers to `/opt/local/lib` which when I run:

```
otool -LD /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
```

Message:

> /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0) /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.0.0)

It shows that the version is different than what `httpd` is erring out as.

I have a feeling I need to recompile Apache using newer libraries, but the error message still doesn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: How do you start the apache server?

Comment: /usr/sbin/apachectl -k [graceful|restart|stop...]
Apache is running currently, but when I attempt to stop/start/restart (etc.) it the error above kicks out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have files in `/opt/local` I assume you are using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). In this case PHP will have been compiled against Apache in MacPorts (in `/opt/local/bin`), and you will need to configure and start that one, not the default Apple supplied one.

Comment: I've set my path to use use the PHP binary in /opt/local/bin which is fine.  PHP cli is working well, but should I recompile apache as well?  Sorry guys, by no means am I a server admin, just trying to learn a bit here.

Comment: because you havecompiled php against the macports apache and not the one in /usr/sbin and they have different binary APIs